# How to change the language of all Web Applications of the ArcGIS Server manager (for ASP.NET)?

Tags: arcgis-server, asp.net, internationalization

ArcGIS Server manager (ASP.NET) comes by default the English language. I would like to configure it to Portuguese of Brazil.

It is ok if the administrative tool is in English.

But I'd really like is that the maps Labels were in Portuguese. As in the words: Results, "Query Attributes", "Find", and others.

So my users to access my Web Applications in the native language of maps here.

I know I could edit the Labels in Visual Studio (VS), but this is laborious. And my co-workers do not know how to work in VS. Because I'm the Analyst Informatics and they cartographers. VS is complex for them who do not know how to program.

How to configure all Web Application to another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

To do this, simply edit the text file in the Labels:

> > C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ArcGIS\Manager\Modules\Applications\Templates\mv_cs\default.aspx

That way, all the new Web Applications will be ok.

Thankful! ;)